# How to display elements in a matrix form in Angular without tr and td tags

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I've a different requirement this time. I've an array of objects and is 2D, called `staticKpi` and the structure of object is:

```
{
  kpi: string;
  headerString: string;
  footerString: string;
}
```

Each object represent one vital body sign such as Spo2, BP, etc. All KPIs should be displayed in the manner I add them in the array structure. Like below it is 2 rows and 3 columns:

```
this.staticKpi.push(
      [
        {
          kpi: "SpO2",
          headerString: "High: 97 and above",
          footerString: "Low: 94 and below"
        },
        {
          kpi: "Temperature",
          headerString: "High: 100.4 and above",
          footerString: "Low: 94 and below"
        },
        {
          kpi: "BP",
          headerString: "High: 140/90 ",
          footerString: "Low: 90/60"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          kpi: "Respiratoin",
          headerString: "High: 25 per min",
          footerString: "Low: 10 per min"
        },
        {
          kpi: "Pulse rate",
          headerString: "High: 100 and above",
          footerString: "Low: 50 and below"
        },
        {
          kpi: "D-Dimer",
          headerString: "Negative: 0.50 and Less",
          footerString: "Positive: Greater than 0.50"
        }
      ]
    );
```

Here is the template:

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let row of staticKpi">
        <div *ngFor="let widget of row">
            <div> <!--this makes one complete kpi -->
                <h3>{{widget.headerString}}</h3>
                <h2>{{widget.kpi}}</h2>
                <h3>{{widget.footerString}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting all KPIs one below the other as if in one column. How to display them as per array structure. Here's a live model of the same: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k4vg9v).

I'm told not to use table tags at any cost. Please help me achieve this with loops and css (if any). Thanks.

PS: Please feel free to suggest edit/modify the code.

Comment: Via css you have flex, grid or column-count. Have you tried any?

Comment: Only flex i tried. But I'm not getting the desired result. I don't know if my implementation was wrong. Can you pz look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the following css rules and apply them to the inner div.

```
.rows {
   border: 1px solid black;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 33.33%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

on the template

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let row of staticKpi">
        <div *ngFor="let widget of row" class="rows">   // <-- style applied here
            <div>
                <h3>{{widget.headerString}}</h3>
                <h2>{{widget.kpi}}</h2>
                <h3>{{widget.footerString}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give me some more time. I'll come back to you. Let me show this to my tech lead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your actual stackblitz,
you can also add this to your css

```
.col-4 {
  display:grid; 
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3,1fr);
  /* extra for the demo/fun */
  grid-gap:0.5em;
  align-items:center;
  border-top:solid ;
  box-shadow:0 3px;
  background:linear-gradient(to left,transparent 0  34%,gray 34% 67%, transparent 67% 100%);
  }
```

tpl related to :

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<div>
    <div *ngFor="let row of staticKpi">
        <div class="content-row" *ngFor="let widget of row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <h3>{{widget.headerString}}</h3>
                <h2>{{widget.kpi}}</h2>
                <h3>{{widget.footerString}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```